# Continuous Integration Selenium Webdriver with Azure

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration

I have created a Selenium Webdriver C# script for login module of my app and it's running on my local machine.

Now the things is What is continuous integration. As per my knowledge we can build, test and deploy the app at same time through continuous integration and continuous deployment.

So how I will integrate my Selenium code with my app at Azure and will start Continuous Integration and continuous Deployment. I need help in it from scratch please.

Answer (score 1):

The [CI/CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CI/CD) service for Azure is called [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/). Here you can setup a [pipeline](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/pipelines/) that builds, deploys and tests.

The recent (03/15/2019) Azure DevOps documentation describes [how to run Selenium tests in a pipeline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Niels. Azure devops is a good choice. Just as a note: Typically you will have a separate project for your Selenium tests in your solution. Azure devops have support for running smoke tests after deploying your application to Azure.